# email content to HTML (with php)

Tags: php, html, email

I'm building a simple email program.

I use this to get the HTML: `$bodyHTML = imap_fetchbody($imap, $i, 2);`

When I use: `$bodyHTML = imap_fetchbody($imap, $i, 1.2);` the output is empty...

When I echo the $bodyHTML. I see this:

```
=EF=BB=BF<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC =22-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN=22>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Country Linedance Just Can't See It www.country4all.eu</=
TITLE>
<META name=3DGENERATOR content=3D=22MSHTML 8.00.6001.19019=22>
<STYLE>A:hover {
=09BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow; COLOR: rgb(0,0,153)
}
</STYLE>
```

Now my question is: how can I set this correctly to HTML? (So it shows in the browser)

**UPDATE:
I found that this is a common problem. People advice `$bodyHTML = imap_fetchbody($imap, $i, 1.2);` but most of the times this doesn't work. So people use this:

1) `$bodyHTML = imap_fetchbody($imap, $i, 2);`

2) `quoted_printable_decode($bodyHTML)`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`quoted_printable_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) method to decode the encoded special characters (like `=22`) to regular characters.

Comment: they should give you a statue